# How do I close a android dialog that uese a custom xml file

Tags: android, xml, dialog, android-alertdialog

I have a alertDialog that I build with the AlertDialog.builder.

I then give it a custom xml layoutthat I've made.

in that layout I have imageviews with onclick methods.

When I click them I want to run some code which works great, but I also want to close the Dialog window.

How do I do that? I dont seem to have a reference to the dialog and I cant give a dialog a ID?

Right now Im saving the dialog to a public field and then just close it by pointing to that reference, but that seems like a horrible way of doing it.

Thankful for any help :)

EDIT: my code ` AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

```
    alert.setTitle("Choose Color");
    LayoutInflater inflater = this.getLayoutInflater();
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.colorpicker, null);
    alert.setView(v);
    Dialog d=alert.create();`
```

and the colorpicker layout has 16 different imageviews that run a changecolor method when clicked (that chenges the current color)

Answer (score 0):

To best answer your question we need you to post a code sample but you can try this

```
.setNegativeButton(android.R.string.cancel,new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {
                    // if this button is clicked, just close
                    // the dialog box and do nothing
                    dialog.cancel();
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay I am going to assume that your button for closing is in your layout so what you can do is change

```
Dialog d=alert.create();`
```

to a global variable then set an onclick listener for your button

```
YOUR_BUTTON.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            YOUR_DIALOG.dismiss(); 
        }
    });
```

Comment: I dont have a button for closing :( just have 16 imageviews

Comment: okay then see my previous answer and do alert.setNegativeButton... this will add a button please ref to this http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html#AlertDialog